# The relationship of Adam and Chavah and what does it mean?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit, pentateuch-chumash, parsha

In Parshat B'reishis ch. 3 p. 20 Adam names Chavah. Here Rashi points out that Adam names her earlier and the reason for bringing up the name in this location.

What I'm wondering though is about the nature of their marriage and what lesson it might have for us. Chavah was created from Adam and he names her. It almost sounds like the role of a parent. Do any of the mefarshim discuss this and if so what do they have to say about it?

Comment: I would say the actual question boils down to "Do any mefarshim discuss if there are relationship elements of parent-child between Adam and Chava?". If I am right, perhaps change the title to match.